# How do I prevent ALL my browsers (FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera) from redirecting localhost to https?

Tags: localhost, http-redirect

I can't for the life of me figure out why suddenly ALL MY INSTALLED browsers (FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera) redirect all my development projects under localhost to https!

This drives me absolutely bunkers. I've tried ALL the (non) solutions I was able to find by googling, and that's A LOT I can tell you. But NONE of these work. HOW do I gain control over HOW my browser acts once and for all, and disable this lame redirect for localhost?

Comment: You may have put a [hsts header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security) in some app you are testing. See this. https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome

Comment: No, I've never had to fiddle with this before ... it just suddenly happened out of the blue for no reason what so ever ... and it goes for ALL browsers. So SOMETHING must have changed SOMEWHERE without my knowledge.

Comment: it sounds like you think there is one common cause (the server on localhost). You should provide more information on that and a log snippet of the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't accidentally download the .access file from the server which contain this stuff:

```
# BEGIN HTTPS Redirect
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# END HTTPS Redirect

# BEGIN Fix mixed content warnings
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
</IfModule>
# END Fix mixed content warnings
```

There's another half day wasted ... sigh!